# upload excel file for specific user in laravel-8 General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-excel

The idea is

1. a user have many data but all data belongsto one user
   i am fasing SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `projects` (`name`, `detail`, `color`, `image`, `logo`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (shahed, kjfs, fsdkf, fdsfsd, fds, 2021-05-30 08:45:35, 2021-05-30 08:45:35)) error.
   If you neen more detail you can ask
   This is my model project.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo','user_id'
    ];

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is model user.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function getProducts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');

    }

    public function getProject(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
    // public function products(){
    //     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    // }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

This is project table projecttable.php

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // $table->('id');
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('detail', 500)->nullable();
            $table->string('color', 255)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('image', 22)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('logo', 22)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

This is importProject.php

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Project([
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'detail'    => $row['detail'],
            'color'    => $row['color'],
            'image'    => $row['image'],
            'logo'    => $row['logo'],
        ]);
    }
```

This is projectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Imports\ProjectsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(20);
        // $projects = Project::paginate(20);


        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'logo' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        Project::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $user_id =  Auth::user()->id ;

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'logo' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $project->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }

    public function importProject()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProjectsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Project created successfully.');
    }

    public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'projects.xlsx');
    }
}
```

this is index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a class="btn btn-success text-light mr-5" data-toggle="medel" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModel"
                    data-attr="{{ route ('projects.create')}}" title="upload project">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ route('importProject') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex">
                        @csrf
                        <input type='file' name="file">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: -60px" title="Import Project">
                            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i></button>

                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success text-light" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                    data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}" title="Create a project"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" width="30%">Details</th>
                <th scope="col">color</th>
                <th scope="col">image</th>
                <th scope="col">logo</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->detail }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->color }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->logo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date_format($project->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>

                            <a class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit text-gray-300"></i>
                            </a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {!! $projects->links() !!}


    <!-- small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- medium modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // display a modal (small modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                    $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

        // display a modal (medium modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
                    $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give auth value in import project like this :)

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Project([
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'detail'    => $row['detail'],
            'color'    => $row['color'],
            'image'    => $row['image'],
            'logo'    => $row['logo'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
        ]);
    }
```